# How do I find where a redirect is occurring on my website

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis

We're moving an instance of a third party, .NET-based website to a Win2016 server, IIS 8, from an external hosting service.  Under the site, there's a WCF web service in a subfolder.  There are no virtual directories or apps.

```
mysite.../Order/v4/service.svc
```

When I browse to pull the wsdl (https://MySite.../Order/v4/Service.svc?wsdl ), it is redirecting to Login.aspx (https://MySite.../Order/v4/Login.aspx).
[image]

Browsing to https://MySite/Order/v4/Service.svc?wsdl redirects to https://MySite/Order/v4/Login.aspx .

- IIS has no default document set / web.config's defaultDocument is commented out.
- Vendor indicates

> That would be a redirect that was setup either on IIS or another
>   appliance that is doing that.

- Same behavior occurs running on the server itself (localhost) and sys eng confirms it shouldn't be leaving the network to hit any firewall.
- There are no other .config files on the server with any reference to "Login.aspx".

This still feels like it is some piece of configuration but even doing things I shouldn't need to do like restarting the server just to make sure no caching of settings is hanging around isn't affecting it.

Any guesses on what might be attempting to redirect?

Comment: Enable Failed Request Tracing and capture StatusCodes 300-399.   Instructions for configuring it: 
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2012/01/02/enable-and-activate-failed-request-tracing-rules/

Comment: @Rich-Lang Thanks for the suggestion.  Trying it out and trying to make sense of what all it's giving back ;)

Comment: @Rich-Lang This really helped.  I could identify references to the Global.asax shortly before the header value was replaced with the login.aspx-referencing version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Rich-Lang's suggestion in comments provided the information to identify that the global.asax file was handling an error in the web.config.  Since  the code in this case was in codebehind in a dll, and the vendor indicated their code does not redirect, I had not seen that culprit before.  Removing the global.asax and turning off customErrors allowed me to see the underlying issue.